# .htaccess and HTTP_COOKIE value

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cakephp

In my .htaccess files:
For proper Cookies I use this, that's OK if I check whether there exists a cookie.

```
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} (my\_cookie) [NC]
```

But when I tried to check for zero values and use these choices, it fails to match cases:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ^.*my\_cookie=0.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} my\_cookie=0 [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} (my\_cookie=0) [NC]
```

When I make `print_r ( $_COOKIE );` I get this:

```
Array
(
    [analytics] => true
    [CakeCookie] => Array
        (
            [my_cookie] => 0
            [newuser] => 1
        )
)
```

How can I check the cookie value for this case?

Comment: Maybe `CakeCookie=.*my_cookie\=0.*`? I've never tried rewriting based on cookie values though, so this is just a stab in the dark.

Comment: Nope.. not worked. Even this didn't help. ````CakeCookie=.*authorized=1.*$````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After too many tryouts, this solved my issue:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} CakeCookie.*my\_cookie.*=0
```

I still don't know what would be exact pattern instead of `.*`
but this one works.

Answer (score 2):

Im using same solution for handle language:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} lang=([^;]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?lang=%1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

but I checking value in php file.
I hope that it will be helpful for u ;)